# I want to pass argument to a unchangeable function who's argument are stored in a list?

Tags: python, list, function, arguments

```
def example(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, args3): return arg1+arg2
```

**Imagine that**, example is a python inbuilt function and it can't be modified.

`Args = [12,22,16,62,25]`

```
example(arg for arg in Args)
```

But it is not possible to paas list element as argument :(

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the list of Args as eg:

```
Args = [12,22,16,62,25]
example(*Args)
```